# TSQL Table Value Function Parameter different behavior if parameter a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table value function in TSQL that works well if I pass a string but not if I pass a varchar.

For example, this works:

```
SELECT * from [dbo].[SplitString]('ta;aa;qq', ';')
```

[image]

This does not work:

```
declare @invarchar as varchar
set @invarchar = 'ta;aa;qq'
SELECT * from [dbo].[SplitString](@invarchar, ';')
```

[image]

If you are curious about the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (
        @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Delim VARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
        RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
              CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
            FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
              FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
              WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
              AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
          ) AS y
        );
GO
```

I have the same result with multiple table value function, so I guess that my problem is in the way I call it from the variable that is wrong. How can I use a variable and still have the same output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default length of `VARCHAR` when declared without a length is `1` or sometimes `30`. In your scenario, it defaults to `1`. That's why you're only seeing 1 row with `t` as a result. You should declare `@invarchar` as `VARCHAR(MAX)`, or simply add a length.

```
DECLARE @invarchar as `VARCHAR(MAX)`
```

See this [article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) by Aaron Bertrand for more information.